# Why does my smoke domain stretch the simulation?

Tags: physics, transforms, smoke-simulation

Trying to set up a basic simulation and hitting a few problems.
Will separate out into a few questions though.

My first issue is when I resize the domain object for a simple cube using quick smoke, the simulation stretches with it and doesn't refresh. I'm using eevee, but nothing changes in the other render engines.

Thank you[image: domain]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When resizing any object relating to a simulation (domain, flow, rigid body, etc.) you should always <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, Apply Scale to ensure Blender is aware of it's new dimensions (actually, whenever you rescale anything it's generally a good idea to Apply Scale anyway - uneven scale can cause all kinds of problems with simulations, texturing, etc.). In your case, you should just need to Apply Scale and then re-bake the simulation.

Comment: Great thank you, helpful to know! Still didn't work at first, but I switched the cache type to final so I could force the bake, and it worked fine. Think there might be a few bugs in 'Replay' mode, as it doesn't seem to update very well. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Excellent - glad to help. Yeah - I've had problems with Replay not updating the cache. Sometimes have to change something (eg, just click in the Resolution field and then press Enter - this seems to be enough to invalidate the cache). I guess it'll get fixed at some point.

Comment: Just out of interest before I make a separate question for it, don't suppose you know how to make the emission closer to the original mesh? The sim always starts with the smoke volume scaled larger than the emitter (can see the effect if you just apply quick smoke to the default cube).

Comment: No worries, found it. In the flow object I just needed switch the values of the surface and volume emission.